# Optimizing ltrim and strpos

Tags: php, optimization, explode, strpos

I run scripts similar to the one below on a regular where I am removing a leading character, and then dropping the rest of the string after a character, but I've noticed a very slight drag in loading my page recently, I was wondering if anyone could advise how to optimize something as

```
$user_image ="";
$sqlimage ="SELECT * FROM `sys_users` WHERE `username`='sample'";
$dataimage = sql_fetch($sqlimage);
```

(And this is where I manipulate the data

```
$user_image=$dataimage[0]["image"];
$user_image = substr($user_image, 1);
list($user_image)= explode('|', $user_image);
if (sys_is_super_admin($_SESSION["username"])) $user_image = '/ext/icons/placeholder.gif';
$_SESSION["user_image"] = $user_image;
```

an example

Comment: 1) How often does the above code run? 2) If you time the above code using `microtime()`, how long does it take? 3) Did you index `sys_users`?

Comment: @Mr.Llama Response 1) the code runs about 200 times a day, but this sort of code runs about 1500 times a day 2) Takes about 0.089-0.1seconds 3) it is indexed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use your database if you're super_admin, as well as I can read...

Then, maybe you can use strpos to find the index of your first char limit (the pipe in your example) and use it as a length parameter for your substr.

I can propose you this snippet:

```php
function setSessionUserImage()
{
    if (sys_is_super_admin($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_image'] = '/ext/icons/placeholder.gif';
        return;
    }

    // $mysqli is your instance of mysql connection (from mysqli native PHP class)
    $stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM `sys_users` WHERE `username`= ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($dataimage);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if (!empty($dataimage[0]) && !empty($dataimage[0]['image'])) {
            $user_image = $dataimage[0]['image'];
            // Here, add -1 for the strpos because you're removing the 1st char, shifting the string
            $_SESSION['user_image'] = substr($user_image, 1, strpos($user_image, '|') - 1);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Of course, this snippet assumes there's a pipe into the data you got from your query... And you need to check all error cases to manage them wisely.

Comment: there are pipes on either end of the field image, also I miswrote the sql_fetch, it should be `username`='$username', having a hell of a time getting the syntax right for that. Can you edit your answer to reflect that? I also like your idea to make it into a seperate function and call it accordingly. So i'd write setSessionUserImage($username); in it's place only (?) -- you are right about the super admin not requiring the db, it'd be if (sys_is_super_admin($username)) { or with $_SESSION["username"]

Comment: If you want to use the username stored in your $_SESSION, there's no need to add a param to your function. Also, be careful with SQL injection. I don't know if you're using mysqli, PDO or something else since sql_fecth isn't a native PHP function.

Comment: thanks, yes, sql_fetch is a command that supports multiple databases, so we're using mysqli, but if another DB is setup then could be PDO for them.